# Minecraft pc Alex Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a ZTE and I downloaded the update for Minecraft and I have an Alex skin, and I picked a different skin but it's still Alex. I re-downloaded the skin, it didn't work. I uninstalled Minecraft and re-installed it. Still doesn't work. The app I am using to change my skin is 'World of Skins'. I also reinstalled the app. Nothing is working, someone help please!

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work because i am on mobile,  but i dont have a pc yet.    .-.

Comment: What even is a zte?

Answer (score 0):

Skin changing apps on mobile are pretty unreliable. You'd have to be lucky to find one that actually works, so I recommend simply changing the skin from your computer instead. I have a [Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBah0hBnA2s) that shows you exactly how to do so.